IntelliJ IDEA docker plugin can not build image when using remote docker instance
I using version2024.1.5 and docker version 27.0.2,
when I click build image but only show "Deploying 'cron Dockerfile: Dockerfile'…" in build logs.
My remote connect to docker is normal, but I do not know why it now not work.
Does anyone know why?

This is the log I found：
2024-07-21 14:23:12,153 [   8547]   WARN - #c.i.e.c.PtyCommandLine - Couldn't run process with PTY
com.pty4j.windows.conpty.LastErrorExceptionEx: CreateProcessW failed: GetLastError() returned 2: The system can not find the file specified.
    at com.pty4j.windows.conpty.ProcessUtils.start(ProcessUtils.java:91)
    at com.pty4j.windows.conpty.ProcessUtils.startProcess(ProcessUtils.java:25)
    at com.pty4j.windows.conpty.WinConPtyProcess.<init>(WinConPtyProcess.java:42)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcessBuilder.start(PtyProcessBuilder.java:139)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessServiceImpl.startPtyProcess(ProcessServiceImpl.kt:37)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.PtyCommandLine.startProcessWithPty(PtyCommandLine.java:172)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.PtyCommandLine.startProcess(PtyCommandLine.java:112)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:357)
    at com.intellij.docker.cli.CliExecutor$doCreateProcess$2.invokeSuspend(CliExecutor.kt:153)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)


I create issue for jetbrains:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-158791/docker-plugin-CreateProcessW-failed-GetLastError-returned-2-The-system-can-not-find-the-file-specified.

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3 version, at least local Docker CLI is necessary to build images or execute Docker Compose configurations on the remote Docker Engine. For the details on how to do it, please check this article in our Knowledge Base.
